# After "git clone ..." how do you add that folder to current directory as 1 single repo?

Tags: git

I am trying Git, and so if i do

```
mkdir foo
cd foo
git clone git://github.com/some_repo/sdk.git
```

so my project folder will now have `sdk`, which is a library or an sdk.  How to make `sdk` part of my project now?  That is, just 1 repo instead of `git init` and have 2 separate repos?

Comment: What you're describing is the exact use case for git submodules; similar to svn externals.  I suggest using the library/sdk as a submodule.

Comment: you mean better separate and not as 1 repo?

Comment: Your proj repo will reference the other one and use it as such.

Comment: @動靜能量 It depends if your project and sdk are the same project. If sdk is an independent software, than submodule is the way to go. If your project and sdk are the same software, it could be a benefit to include your project into the sources of sdk. When in doubt use submodules.

Answer (score 1):

If project `sdk`:

- is not developed at the same pace than your `foo` project (i.e. changing anything in `foo` doesn't always involve changing `sdk`, and changing `sdk` doesn't mean changing `foo`)
- must have `sdk` as a sub-directory

, then, as [Scott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/350837/scott) comments, a submodule approach is useful, because (as I describe in "[true nature of submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979167/git-submodule-update/1979194#1979194)") you will be able to:

- reference a specific version of `sdk`
- while still being able to modify `sdk` directly from within your `foo` project.

Yes, they will be two separate repos, but you can still manage them from the parent repo `foo`.

Comment: One repo would mean " **subtree merging** " (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/908087/how-to-version-project-schedules-to-dos-wikis-etc-in-git/908892#908892), but you would loose any link between sdk and its original github repo.