# To show external code dependency in Git by a submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

**Solved Problem:** to show external code dependency by submodules: *Thanks to [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145422/to-show-external-folder-dependency-in-git-by-a-submodule/1145618#1145618)!*

**Current Problem:** to have [a submodule without duplicate contents in two folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145422/to-show-external-folder-dependency-in-git/1147178#1147178)

**A temporary solution to the current problem:** to change the name of the folder to bin-github, since the name of the folder as a submodule is bin. This means I need to duplicate contents at my Home.

My HOME folder is dependent on ~/bin.
I have files located at HOME at the repository *Masi*, while at ~/bin at the repo *bin* at Github. My relevant folder structure at Home:

```
~
|-- [drwxr-xr-x] bin
    | -- fileA
    ` -- folderA
    ...
```

I would like to know how to show make ~/bin a submodule of the Git at *Masi*.

**How can you make ~/bin a submodule of my Git at ~/ ?**

---

**#3 Reply to VonC's comment:**

**My .gitmodules**

```
[submodule "bin"]   
         path = bin
         url = git://github.com/masi/bin.git
```

I feel that I do not need to add anymore the submodule again, since I have it in my .gitmodules.

I run

```
Sam master $ git submodule update
Sam master $ git submodule foreach git pull
Sam master $ ls bin
```

---

**#2 Reply to VonC's answer:**

I changed my .gitmodules to the following such that I do not have a duplicate copy of it in my home.

```
[submodule "bin"]
    path = bin
    url = git://github.com/masi/bin.git
```

This seems to be a different situation as I cannot pull the submodule-bin -folder similarly as above.

I get the following now at a fresh-cloned git-repo

```
Sam master $ git submodule git init
error: pathspec 'git' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'init' did not match any file(s) known to git.
Did you forget to 'git add'?                          # I am not sure what this means
Sam master $ git submodule foreach git pull
Sam master $ git submodule update
```

I have the external repository in my .gitmodules. Why is it asking me to `git add`?

---

**Reply to VonC's answer:**

I run

```
git submodule add git://github.com/masi/bin.git bin-github-copy
```

because I cannot add a new repo with the same name as my existing folder `bin`.

My .gitmodules is

```
[submodule "bin-github-copy"]
    path = bin-github-copy
    url = git://github.com/masi/bin.git
```

I run

```
git clone git://github.com/masi/Sam.git
```

I get an emty bin -directory.

**How can I get the content of bin?**

Comment: I will open a new question about the current problem to a new thread to clarify things.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, Masi, I kind of lost track of that post. I try to dig into your current issue in your new thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, do not forget that with Git, you can not "add" a directory, only the content of at least one file within that directory.

Then you have two choices:

- [submodules](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule), in order for Masi to refer a specific commit of your `[`files within a`]` bin directory stored at GitHub (or to the latest commit of a branch, stored at GitHub)
- [subtree merge](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/using-merge-subtree.html), in order to mix the two repositories together and more easily follow  modifications to files within bin directly from the Masi repository. That may be simpler in your scenario.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899373/transferring-legacy-code-base-from-cvs-to-distributed-repository-e-g-git-or-mer/899428#899428) for more on those 2 strategies.

---

On the submodules path, declaring the submodule is only half the work. You still have to initialize your submodule the first time by

```
git submodule git init
```

You need then [pull your submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030169/git-easy-way-pull-latest-of-all-submodules):

```
git submodule foreach git pull
```

and then update your submodule

```
git submodule update
```

See also this practical example with [Git submodules, part I](http://daniel.collectiveidea.com/blog/2008/04/08/git-submodules/) and [Git submodules, part II](http://daniel.collectiveidea.com/blog/2008/04/12/git-submodules-part-2/).

> The `.gitmodules` file only stores the paths, but the commit version does get stored with the main project.
>   I created a [project on GitHub](https://github.com/danielmorrison/submodule_example/) to demonstrate what happens. Specifically look at [this commit](https://github.com/danielmorrison/submodule_example/commit/59276847188833650403ea980716f92a4a9fbc0c), which adds the submodule, to see what’s going on:

```
+Subproject commit 60be4b09f51d2560802ebd744893bb6f737ef57c
```

Comment: @ Please, see 2nd reply to your answer.

Comment: @ Please, see my reply to your comment below.

Comment: I opened a new thread based on your answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155095/unable-to-git-submodule-foreach-git-pull

Comment: @RobKennedy: link restored and references added.