# Unable to `git submodule foreach git pull`

Tags: git, repository, git-submodules, git-pull

This question is based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145422/to-show-external-code-dependency-in-git-by-a-submodule).

**My .gitmodules is at my Home**

```
[submodule "bin"]
           path = bin
           url = git://github.com/masi/bin.git
```

**My folder -structure at my Home:**

```
~
|-- [drwxr-xr-x] bin          // this is the folder which I make a submodule
                              // it is also a folder where I have a Git to push my submodule's files
    | -- fileA
    ` -- folderA
    ...
```

I run

```
git submodule init    # I get no output from these commands
git submodule update
```

I run

```
git submodule foreach git pull
```

I get

```
Entering 'bin'
fatal: Where do you want to fetch from today?
Stopping at 'bin'; script returned non-zero status.
```

My first assumption to fix the bug was to change `path = bin` to `path = /Users/Masi/bin`. However, this does not solve the problem.

**How can you upload the content from the external repository which is a submodule in my Git?**

Comment: What does the .git/config look like for your bin submodule?

Comment: @Charles: My .git/config is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155095/unable-to-git-submodule-foreach-git-pull/1155850#1155850

Comment: It looks like your bin submodule is recursive??

Comment: @ Why do you think that bin submodule is recursive?

Comment: If the `.git/config` file for your bin submodule also contains a `[submodule "bin"]` section, then the submodule may be recursive (that is, it includes itself as a submodule). This will probably lead to much confusion.

Comment: @Greg: Please, see my answer to your comment at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155095/unable-to-git-submodule-foreach-git-pull/1157765#1157765

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is normally the error made when there is no remote configured.
(From [this thread](http://osdir.com/ml/git/2009-03/msg01535.html))

It was a patch introduced to at least fixes the regression when running "git pull" in a repository initialized a long time ago that does not use the `.git/config` file to specify where my remote repositories are.

> a better message would probably be something like:
>
> No default remote is configured for your current branch, and the default remote "origin" is not configured, either.
>
> I think the message missed being made user-friendly in earlier passes due to being inaccessible at the time.

---

So this message indicates the remote repo mentioned in .git/modules is not declared in .git/config

From [git submodule](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule)

Submodules are not to be confused with remotes, which are meant mainly for branches of the same project;
submodules are meant for different projects you would like to make part of your source tree, while the history of the two projects still stays completely independent, and you cannot modify the contents of the submodule from within the main project.

I believe you may have missed the step of `git submodule init`:

submodule init

> Initialize the submodules, **i.e. register each submodule name and url found in .gitmodules into .git/config**.
> The key used in `.git/config` is `submodule.$name.url`.
> This command does not alter existing information in .git/config.
> You can then customize the submodule clone URLs in `.git/config` for your local setup and proceed to `git submodule update`; you can also just use `git submodule update --init` without the explicit init step if you do not intend to customize any submodule locations.

If your remote repo (declared in .git/modules) is adequately referenced in .git/config, you should not have this error message anymore.

Before using (pullin) submodules, the steps:

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

remain necessary.

---

Note: Git 2.42 (Q3 2023) rewrites the description of giving a custom command to the `submodule.<name>.update` configuration variable.

See [commit 7cebc5b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7cebc5bd786a95722dc545a2cad22124ec996c00) (25 Jul 2023) by [Petar Vutov (`pvutov`)](https://github.com/pvutov).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit a53e8a6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a53e8a64884dffb23ea416687ae8fbdaf332641a), 04 Aug 2023)</sup>

> ### [`doc`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7cebc5bd786a95722dc545a2cad22124ec996c00): highlight that `.gitmodules` does not support `!command`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Petar Vutov</sup>

> Bugfix for [fc01a5d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fc01a5d26a8f0f80db8302d3ef3ce10924a68581) ("submodule update documentation: don't repeat ourselves", 2016-12-27, Git v2.12.0-rc2 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2f4e87d7777a0bcffa8a7cc3cc52e1e8b2c352ff)).
>
> The `custom command` and `none` options are described as sharing the same limitations, but one is allowed in `.gitmodules` and the other is not.
>
> Rewrite the description for custom commands to be more precise, and make it easier for readers to notice that custom commands cannot be used in the `.gitmodules` file.

`git submodule` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7cebc5bd786a95722dc545a2cad22124ec996c00/Documentation/git-submodule.txt#L108-L113):

> It will also copy the value of `submodule.$name.update`, if present in
> the `.gitmodules` file, to `.git/config`, but (1) this command does not
> alter existing information in `.git/config`, and (2) `submodule.$name.update`
> that is set to a custom command is *not* copied for security reasons.
>
> You can then customize the submodule clone URLs in `.git/config`

Comment: I run those steps - I clarify my question.

Comment: In other words, the same problem occurs with the commands too.

Comment: Nice point. I encountered the similar problem and it turned out that I had accidentally rename the remote repo from origin to upstream, in one of my submodule. Correct the repo name to origin, then Git gives some more practical advice -- If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with: "git branch --set-upstream master origin/<branch>".