# git pull --rebase fails with submodule foreach but succeeds on its own directory

Tags: git, git-submodules

[update at bottom]

This has now happened twice in last fifteen minutes. When I issue the following command from parentmodule

```
git submodule foreach git pull --rebase
```

It prints messages about updating some submodules and 'is up to date.' about some other until stopping at one with the following:

```
Entering 'foo.bar'
Cannot pull with rebase: You have unstaged changes.
Please commit or stash them.
Stopping at 'foo.bar'; script returned non-zero status.
```

I do not remember making any changes in foo.bar. As a matter of fact I had issued `git submodule foreach git status` immediately before this where it had reported up to date. So I try to see what is wrong and there seems to be nothing wrong:

```
$ cd foo.bar/
14 07 17 12:38:03 I063510@OAKN00563024A /c/git/mainbuild/foo.bar (staging)
$ git st
On branch staging
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/staging'.

nothing to commit, working directory clean
14 07 17 12:38:08 I063510@OAKN00563024A /c/git/mainbuild/foo.bar (staging)
$ git pull --rebase
remote: Counting objects: 19, done        
remote: Finding sources: 100% (10/10)        
remote: Total 10 (delta 5), reused 9 (delta 5)        
Unpacking objects: 100% (10/10), done.
From ssh://git.wdf.sap.corp:29418/smp/server/dist/com.sap.mobile.platform.server.foo.bar
   214e0c9..266b279  master     -> origin/master
Current branch staging is up to date.
```

**So why did it fail with submodule foreach?**

**UPDATE**
It seems `git submodule` is not to be blamed here. I tried

```
git submodule  -q foreach 'echo "cd $name;  pwd; git pull --rebase; cd .."' | bash
```

and that failed too. Then I tried the original command in a new `cygwin bash` started from windows command prompt that did not execute my `~/.bash_profile` etc. And it succeeded. So there is something else that is causing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this was caused by my `~/.git-prompt.sh` which was getting sourced for non-interactive shells also.

The problem disappeared after I protected `source ~/.git-prompt.sh; PS1=....` inside `[[ $- == *i* ]]` in my `~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 1):

Git submodules are so broken. I'm not sure if they fixed the problem since I last used it. But there is no good way to update a submodule branch because, your git head file (I think that's what its called) stores current commit it a hard coded very hard to update manner. I found myself literally having to delete the entire submodule from the repo and then putting it back for every update. (Better explained in my link)

make sure you `.git/configure` is correctly assigned and you run these two commands when you update the sub module.

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

I still found it pretty painful to use just be aware.

---

There are two posts worth looking at.

[Overview of Gitsubmodules](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/03/git-submodules-workflows-tips/#tip5)

[Why Git Pull Doesn't Work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155095/unable-to-git-submodule-foreach-git-pull)