# int main() first defined here errors

Tags: c++, eclipse

I just started learning c++ today by doing Project Euler problems. My issue is that in Java, I can organize the problems into their own packages, but how do I do that in c++?

The image below shows my Java/c++ setup. The Java part works perfectly for me, however, I can't do the same in c++ (using folders and namespaces) without getting "multiple definition of main" errors.

[image]

How can I fit all the individual problems inside the "Project Euler C++" folder? Thanks

**Edit:** After hours of searching, I found that [**this post**](http://tinyguides.blogspot.com/2013/04/multiple-binaries-in-single-eclipse-cdt.html?showComment=1370752586119#c3444094958615671327) had the best and easiest solution for my problem

Comment: Unless you compile with the command line, separate them into separate projects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In c and c++ you can only have one main() function. I'm guessing the problem here is that Problem1.cpp and Problem2.cpp are in the same project, but each have a main() function. Look up how to use header files, and then include the header files in your main program.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem has little to do with C++, and much to do with Eclipse (n.b. the NetBeans IDE is no better, and I'm sure plenty of others too).  You've got a single Eclipse project, but multiple definitions of `main()`, each of which needs to go in its own executable file.

See here for more details and some suggestions: [Project with multiple binaries in Eclipse CDT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617414/project-with-multiple-binaries-in-eclipse-cdt)

You could also write a single `main()` which dispatches to multiple other "sub-main" functions based on , say, the first command-line argument.  Some programs behave this way, including many version control systems (e.g. `git add` and `git commit` which both invoke one program but then farm out the work based on the first argument).