# Is it possible to have a git repository as a "vendor branch" in subversion?

Tags: svn, git, vendor-branch

Is it possible to have a git repository as a "vendor branch" in subversion?

In this project we will have several parts, but some parts will use svn and some will use git.
So I am looking into a "project root" from where we can have the other projects as vendor branches (or similar).

And the question is if it is possible manage this "project root" with subversion?

Thanks 
Johan

---

The inverse question can be found here:

- [Is it possible to have a subversion repository as a “submodule” in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201396/is-it-possible-to-have-a-subversion-repository-as-a-submodule-in-git)

---

*Update*:

Thanks VonC for pointing out that the answer is **"no it is not possible"**.
but the inverse is (so I will probably focus on that question instead).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rather:

- git-svn the parts managed by svn
- use **git submodules** for the root project (see [git submodules true nature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979167/git-submodule-update/1979194#1979194))

Svn externals could include other svn parts, but not the git parts (and [external is quite different from git submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131912/why-are-git-submodules-incompatible-with-svn-externals/3132221#3132221)).

Comment: Thanks, so it seems that this way is not possible