# Is it possible to have a subversion repository as a "submodule" in git?

Tags: svn, git, git-submodules

Is it possible to have a subversion repository as a "submodule" in git?

In this project we will have several parts, but some parts will use svn and some will use git. So I am looking into a "project root" from where we can have the other projects as submodules (or similar).

And the question is if it is possible manage this "project root" with git?

Thanks 
Johan

---

The inverse question can be found here:

- [Is it possible to have a git repository as a “vendor branch” in subversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201360/is-it-possible-to-have-a-git-repository-as-a-vendor-branch-in-subversion)

---

*Update*:

In the inverse question VonC gave a tip that this could be done with git-svn, 
does anybody have a example on how this could look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if the subversion repo is first cloned as a git repo: see **[`git-svn`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn)**.
Once there are cloned, you can make some modifications in the git repo and '`dcommit`' them to the svn repo, or you can update your git repo with svn repo evolutions.

Example: [Git - SVN Crash Course](http://git.or.cz/course/svn.html)

Comment: Other tutorials are available out there: http://trac.parrot.org/parrot/wiki/git-svn-tutorial, http://orestis.gr/blog/2008/08/23/git-svn-tutorial/, ...