# How to modify git repository to add submodules in ALL the past revisions?

Tags: git, migration, git-svn, git-submodules, git-filter-branch

I migrated my SVN repository successfully with Tags into Git using `git svn-clone`. However, `git svn-clone` does not migrate `svn:externals`. Hence, I decided to modify branch tree using `git filter-branch`.

For `svn:externals`, first I created a separate Git repository for each svn:externals and then I tried using the following, but it didn't work.

```
$ git filter-branch --tree-filter "git submodule add git@github.com:myAcc/mySubmodule.git mySubmodule" HEAD
Rewrite a013a219e4294d4ee66b323cf1db9c170d90130a (1/4)fatal: working tree '.' already exists.
Clone of 'git@github.com:myAcc/mySubmodule.git' into submodule path 'common' failed
tree filter failed: git submodule add git@github.com:myAcc/mySubmodule.git mySubmodule
rm: cannot remove `c:/myRepo/.git-rewrite/revs': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove directory `c:/myRepo/.git-rewrite': Directory not empty
```

Any idea how to accomplish this? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Don't forget `git submodules` are not exactly an equivalent of `svn:externals`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131912/why-are-git-submodules-incompatible-with-svn-externals/3132221#3132221

Comment: Thanks for the caveat. I overlooked the fact that `git submodule` actually points to a commit. Not sure in this case, it is an option for me. I want to point the submodule to HEAD every time one updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could do it this way, but it may be possible to do it in a cleaner way:

1. Create temporary empty git repository
2. Add your `svn:external`s to it as submodules and commit; note the SHA name of this commit
3. Go into your old repository
4. `git fetch` from the temporary repository
5. `git rebase <SHA of the only commit in the temporary repository>`

Comment: Actually, it doesn't sound that bad esp. when one is try to migrate SVN repo to Git. Since you don't do it again and again. But now, my main problem lies with git-submodule itself. I want to point my submodule to the HEAD of that module and not to a particular commit. Any insight?

Comment: AFAIK, a submodule always points to a particular commit, you can't point to to HEAD.