# using git filter-branch for submodule checkout

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-filter-branch

I have a git repo with one submodule. I used the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300626/how-to-modify-git-repository-to-add-submodules-in-all-the-past-revisions) to connect them.

Now, I'd like to use filter-branch to check out a specific revision from the submodule for each revision of the superproject. I wrote a script that does that, but checkout doesn't work, because in the temporary root, the submodule doesn't have .git directory...

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Huh? Each revision of the superproject already has a submodule that points to a specific commit of the subproject. The fact that your submodule doesn't have a .git directory seems like a totally unrelated problem.

Comment: In the temporary directory that git creates for filter-branch, there is no .git directory, so I cannot checkout anything...

Comment: I would like to know the answer to this exact question, and the OP's answer (rebase) won't work in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I ended up doing git rebase -i, entering 'edit' for all relevant commits (I could find them with a regexp), and then used a script that does the actual submodule checkout, commit, rebase --continue.

I guess there isn't a straight-forward way to do that...