# ClearCase equivalent of SVN's 'svn:externals'

Tags: svn, clearcase

At work we use ClearCase as our source code repository. I want to find the equivalent of 'svn:externals', but for ClearCase. Is there such a thing?

Comment: What about usual links ? (Unix based environment ?)

Comment: We are hosting in a Windows environment. Is the 'links' just a unix option?

Comment: Related question, a component-based VCS and "svn:external" are not compatible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131912/why-are-git-submodules-incompatible-with-svn-externals/3132221#3132221

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no equivalent in ClearCase to Subversion's `svn:externals` property. The closest you can get is using ClearCase's internal symbolic links via the `cleartool ln -s` command. If you're linking files, you can try using hard links, but they can cause user confusion.

I've had problems with `svn:externals` and have stopped using them. It is way too easy to specify an actively changing HEAD as the `svn:externals` link, and then forget about that when you create a tag. That can cause your tagged version to change without your knowledge.

In order to get around this you should only tag to a specified revision **AND** make sure you use revision pinning since a later revision might move or delete the directory tree you were linking to. (There's a debate whether a link to the `tags` directory counts as a specified version, or whether you really need to use `-r`).

A better way is to treat directories from subcomponents your linking to via things like `svn:exterals` as actual releases and store them on some sort of release server. When you do your *build* of your application, you copy the needed files from the release server to your project much the way Maven and Ant/Ivy do. If your release is really just source code, you can store it on your release server as a tarball.

The big advantage is that this method is now independent of special features in your version control system.

Comment: +1 for release dependencies (in an external referential, imported through ant/ivy/maven), as opposed to source dependencies. Plus this is more detailed than my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not really:

- only [ClearCase UCM](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_proj.doc/c_u_ovw_ch.htm) comes close to be able to reference a set of file with a precise label (baseline)
- there is no way to include a set of file (component) *within* a component