# How do I get External link in Git

Tags: git

I've been using Git for a while. I want simulate a case in SVN using git, that I want to import an external tree into my project. Let's say,

```
my_project_root
  my_folder1
  jQuery(link to external source)
```

How do I do that?

thanks

Comment: Note: git submodules are the right solution, but they are not the same than SVN externals: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131912/why-are-git-submodules-incompatible-with-svn-externals/3132221#3132221

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at git's [submodules](http://book.git-scm.com/5_submodules.html).  A little bit more complicated that what I hoped for but it gets the job done.

Comment: Thanks. Seems to be a solution.