# What's best way to work with git on multiple master branch?

Tags: git, merge, branch

I have a git repo for my work project.
The software is still under development but i have now three different branch "master" each with some little variations (graphical customization and different behaviour).
I cannot merge automatically my development branch with these master branch, because every branch is differnet.
I read about git cherry-pick but my question is: "is this the right way to work?"
I really need this three different version of my project, maybe can i try to separate the "core" with the "customization"  and works with git submoduele?

thanks

Comment: cherry-pick would work if your dev branch is clean (no modifications from the HEAD commit) or you could create a another branch and merge all the three branches to the new branch and then merge your dev branch to it. Learn more at http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use submodules if those variations can be isolated in their own subdirectory (since it is how submodules will be structured within your parent repository: see for instance "[Planning repository layout for git migration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9395375/6309)").
That should be the case for the graphical variations.

If those variations are simple config files differences, you can also use one branch and [content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031800/how-to-keep-different-content-of-one-file-in-my-local-and-github-repository/6031981#6031981) in order to generate the right config file, based on the environment in which the repo is checked out.

I prefer those options to cherry-picking, which can introduces:

- [duplication and functional dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13522664/what-is-cherry-pick-in-git/13524494#13524494),
- [functional dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881092/how-to-merge-a-specific-commit-in-git/881112#881112)

Comment: Write the code isn't the real work of developers. The real work is _manage_ the code :(