# Updating to fmdb 2.0?

Tags: iphone, git

We are usin fmdb and I see that fmdb 2.0 supports multithreaded calls. What is a good way to update to 2.0? Fmdb was added to the project before I got on this project and I dont want to break anything. We are using Git if that helps also. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how "Fmdb was added to the project".

If it is a [submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-6.html), you can simply make a branch in which:

- you will go in that submodule, and git pull the [fmdb 2.0 tag](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb/tags) (that is [this commit](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb/commit/b2047f93ad16bb81226be34b2ae66448698dd2a2): warning, this will result in a [detached HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666085/how-do-i-get-git-clone-recursive-to-recreate-submodules-remotes-and-branche/11451714#11451714))
- go back to the parent repo
- commit (in order to record in the `.gitmodules` the new reference for fmdb)

You can then develop in isolation from the main branch of your project, with fmdb2.0 visible just within that new branch.