# How do I update my git submodules from specific branches?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, git-submodules

I have a Ruby on Rails app that has two git submodules. I am upgrading Rails from v3 to v4 in the main app and in the two submodules, so I created a rails4 branch for each in which to do the work. The main app and each submodule have their own test suites that run independently, so I made the upgrades in the submodules and the project, ensured the tests all run in each place, and now I need to update the submodules into the project.

How do I tell git in my app's rails4 branch to update from the submodules' rails4 branches when I do `git submodule update`? It's ok to have a temporary fix for this as I can point them back at master once the app is confirmed working and the branches all get merged in to master. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> now I need to update the submodules into the project.

The parent repo only records SHA1 (in a special [gitlink entry, mode 160000](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309))

You can, in your `rails4` branch, update your .gitmodules in order to ask your submodule to checkout/update their `rails4` branch: see "[Git submodules: Specify a branch/tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18799234/6309)" for the full process: it starts with:

```
cd /path/to/your/parent/repo
git config -f .gitmodules submodule.<path>.branch <branch>
```

That will allow for a `git submodule update --recursive --remote` to update the `rails4` branch in those submodules.