# Is there any distributed revision control system that supports partial checkout/clone?

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial, dvcs, bazaar

As far as I know all distributed revision control systems require you to clone the whole repository. For this reason is it not wise to put huge amounts of content into one single repository (thanks for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899373/transferring-legacy-code-base-from-cvs-to-distributed-repository-e-g-git-or-mer/899428#899428)). I know that this a not a bug but a feature, but I wonder whether this is a requirement for all distributed revision control systems.

In distributed rcs the history of a file (or a chunk of content) is a directed acyclic graph, so why can't you just clone this single DAG instead of the set of all graphs in the repository? Maybe I miss something but the following use-cases are hard to do:

- clone only a part of a repository
- merge two repositories (preserving their histories!)
- copy some files with their history from one repository to another

If I reuse parts of other people's code from multiple projects I cannot preserve their full history. At least in git I can think of a (rather complex) workaround:

1. clone a full repository
2. delete all content that I am not interested in
3. rewrite the history to delete everything that is not in the master
4. merge the remaining repository into an existing repository

I don't know if this is also possible with Mercurial or Bazaar but at least it is not easy at all. So is there any distributed rcs that supports partial checkout/clone by design? It should support one simple command to get a single file with its history from one repository and merge it into another. This way you would not need to think about how to structure your content into repositories and submodules but you could happily split and merge repositories as needed (the extreme would be one repository for each single file).

Comment: Actually... 10 years later, a partial clone might be possible with Git in the upcoming Git 2.17. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48852630/6309).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of version 2.0, it is not possible to make a so-called ["narrow clone"](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PartialClone) with Mercurial, that is, a clone where you only retrieve data for a specific sub-directory. We call it a "shallow clone" when you only retrieve part of the history, say, the last 100 revisions.

As you say, there is nothing in the common DAG-based history model that excludes this feature and we have been working on it. Peter Arrenbrecht, a Mercurial contributor, has implemented two different approaches for narrow clones, but neither approach has been merged yet.

Btw, you can of course split an existing Mercurial repository into pieces where each smaller repository only has the history for a specific sub-directory of the original repository. The [convert extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension) is the tool for this. Each of the smaller repositories will be unrelated to the bigger repository, though — the tricky part is to make the splitting seamless so that the changesets keep their identities.

Comment: (2017) If you satisfy the requirements it is possible to create a Mercurial repo that supports narrow clones using Google's NarrowHG extension (https://bitbucket.org/Google/narrowhg ) but it's not in mainline Mercurial.

Answer (score 12):

As of Git 2.17 (Q2 2018, 10 years later), it *will* be possible to do what Mercurial planned to implement: a "[narrow clone](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/NarrowClonePlan)", that is, a clone where you only retrieve data for a specific sub-directory.
This is also called "partial clone".

That differs from the current

- [shallow clone](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#git-clone---depthltdepthgt)
- copy of what you need from the cloned repo in another working folder.

See [commit 3aa6694](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3aa6694fb3d38a3afe623ccbdf59fb15f338a94d), [commit aa57b87](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aa57b871dad3cca07abead9a8d1fefceffe7578d), [commit 35a7ae9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/35a7ae952ffee0d47d4f6302163488abea3bf418), [commit 1e1e39b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1e1e39b308fe9dd68a3312992a06270da7dd07af), [commit acb0c57](https://github.com/git/git/commit/acb0c57260aa78fc99939de2a27c48b5a3fb4f21), [commit bc2d0c3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bc2d0c3396fad7b7064c6e9599e6321742538aa0), [commit 640d8b7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/640d8b72feaae0b96d5faa663ad624963e416d54), [commit 10ac85c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/10ac85c785afed4163ed931149a87b30c7c5eaf9) (08 Dec 2017) by [Jeff Hostetler (`jeffhostetler`)](https://github.com/jeffhostetler).
See [commit a1c6d7c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a1c6d7c1a792bd2c60bbfb07597d13f7d0c4eb37), [commit c0c578b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c0c578b33ca48ee6003d85706e13d97d12781354), [commit 548719f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/548719fbdc4ccd5d678afafbb5e3b5c8dac28489), [commit a174334](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a1743343f410290578fbd6e0ada50b8cdf1e7df8), [commit 0b6069f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0b6069fe0a1e694d632e54a43fc6e546e83edad6) (08 Dec 2017) by [Jonathan Tan (`jhowtan`)](https://github.com/jhowtan).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 6bed209](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6bed209a20a06f2d6b7142216dabff456de798e1), 13 Feb 2018)</sup>

Here are the [tests for a partial clone](https://github.com/git/git/commit/35a7ae952ffee0d47d4f6302163488abea3bf418):

```
git clone --no-checkout --filter=blob:none "file://$(pwd)/srv.bare" pc1
```

---

There other [other commits involved in that implementation of a narrow/partial clone](https://github.com/git/git/search?q=partialclone&type=Commits&utf8=%E2%9C%93).

In particular, [commit 8b4c010](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8b4c0103a98239287176a537f7a04d9b07b49125):

> ### sha1_file: support lazily fetching missing objects

> Teach `sha1_file` to fetch objects from the remote configured in
> `extensions.partialclone` whenever an object is requested but missing.

---

Warning regarding Git 2.17/2.18: The recent addition of "partial clone" experimental feature kicked in when it shouldn't, namely, when there is no partial-clone filter defined even if `extensions.partialclone` is set.

See [commit cac1137](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cac1137dc4908b03642ee10c45eb687feb9335c1) (11 Jun 2018) by [Jonathan Tan (`jhowtan`)](https://github.com/jhowtan).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 92e1bbc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/92e1bbc33472d5389d5933f39d37da58e7e03053), 28 Jun 2018)</sup>

> ### `upload-pack`: disable object filtering when disabled by config

> When `upload-pack` gained partial clone support (v2.17.0-rc0~132^2~12,
> 2017-12-08), it was guarded by the `uploadpack.allowFilter` config item
> to allow server operators to control when they start supporting it.
>
> That config item didn't go far enough, though: it controls whether the
> '`filter`' capability is advertised, but if a (custom) client ignores
> the capability advertisement and passes a filter specification anyway,
> the server would handle that despite allowFilter being false.
>
> This is particularly significant if a security bug is discovered in
> this new experimental partial clone code.
> Installations without `uploadpack.allowFilter` ought not to be affected since they don't intend to support partial clone, but they would be swept up into being
> vulnerable.

---

This is enhanced with Git 2.20 (Q2 2018), since "`git fetch $repo $object`" in a partial clone did not correctly fetch the asked-for object that is referenced by an object in promisor packfile, which has been fixed.

See [commit 35f9e3e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/35f9e3e5e7a6436b50a8709e7e14a65a10cc1e7a), [commit 4937291](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4937291b45800372c2c34855a6a36d5d2a77af2c) (21 Sep 2018) by [Jonathan Tan (`jhowtan`)](https://github.com/jhowtan).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit a1e9dff](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a1e9dff182b19a2620aab036c22389d22b9dd0be), 19 Oct 2018)</sup>

> ### `fetch`: in partial clone, check presence of targets

> When fetching an object that is known as a promisor object to the local
> repository, the connectivity check in [`quickfetch()` in `builtin/fetch.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blame/4937291b45800372c2c34855a6a36d5d2a77af2c/builtin/fetch.c#L934)
> succeeds, causing object transfer to be bypassed.
> However, this should not happen if that object is merely promised and not actually present.
>
> Because this happens, when a user invokes "`git fetch origin <sha-1>`" on
> the command-line, the `<sha-1>` object may not actually be fetched even
> though the command returns an exit code of 0. This is a similar issue
> (but with a different cause) to the one fixed by [a0c9016](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a0c9016abd566e9a8f988dcd387663cd0b2be078)
> ("upload-pack: send refs' objects despite "filter"", 2018-07-09, Git v2.19.0-rc0).
>
> Therefore, [update `quickfetch()`](https://github.com/git/git/blame/35f9e3e5e7a6436b50a8709e7e14a65a10cc1e7a/builtin/fetch.c#L934) to also directly check for the presence
> of all objects to be fetched.

---

You can list objects of a partial clone, excluding "promisor" objects, with [`git rev-list --exclude-promisor-objects`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list#git-rev-list---exclude-promisor-objects)

> (For internal use only.) Prefilter object traversal at promisor boundary.
> **This is used with partial clone**.
> This is stronger than `--missing=allow-promisor` because it limits the traversal, rather than just silencing errors about missing objects.

But make sure to use Git 2.21 (Q1 2019) to avoid segfault.

See [commit 4cf6786](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4cf67869b2ae3df7ab76b03c627f7b72d18d24ce) (05 Dec 2018) by [Matthew DeVore (`matvore`)](https://github.com/matvore).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c333fe7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c333fe73682b182d6872f9e5b454c2899c6203ab), 14 Jan 2019)</sup>

> "`git rev-list --exclude-promisor-objects`" had to take an object that does not exist locally (and is lazily available) from the command line without barfing, but the code dereferenced NULL.

### `list-objects.c`: don't segfault for missing cmdline objects

> When a command is invoked with both `--exclude-promisor-objects`, `--objects-edge-aggressive`, and a missing object on the command line, the `rev_info.cmdline` array could get a NULL pointer for the value of an '`item`' field.
> Prevent dereferencing of a `NULL` pointer in that situation.

---

Note that Git 2.21 (Q1 2019) fixes a bug:

See [commit bbcde41](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bbcde41a70a7e0264c214896aac84d1ec3fdcbf6) (03 Dec 2018) by [Matthew DeVore (`matvore`)](https://github.com/matvore).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 6e5be1f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6e5be1f2d5bac42c28a126d382bf7b7bdcb9b7f3), 14 Jan 2019)</sup>

> ### `exclude-promisor-objects`: declare when option is allowed

> The `--exclude-promisor-objects` option causes some funny behavior in at
> least two commands: `log` and `blame`.
> It causes a BUG crash:
>
> ```
> $ git log --exclude-promisor-objects
> BUG: revision.c:2143: exclude_promisor_objects can only be used
> when fetch_if_missing is 0
> Aborted
> [134]
> ```
>
> Fix this such that the option is treated like any other unknown option.
> The commands that must support it are limited, so declare in those commands that the flag is supported.
> In particular:
>
> ```
> pack-objects
> prune
> rev-list
> ```
>
> The commands were found by searching for logic which parses `--exclude-promisor-objects` outside of `revision.c`.
> Extra logic outside of `revision.c` is needed because `fetch_if_missing` must be turned on before `revision.c` sees the option or it will BUG-crash. The above list is supported by the fact that no other command is introspectively invoked by another command passing `--exclude-promisor-object`.

---

Git 2.22 (Q2 2019) optimizes narrow clone:
While running "`git diff`" in a lazy clone, we can upfront know which
missing blobs we will need, instead of waiting for the on-demand
machinery to discover them one by one.
Aim to achieve better performance by batching the request for these promised blobs.

See [commit 7fbbcb2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7fbbcb21b162883615d5542e06fb2eb8685fd496) (05 Apr 2019), and [commit 0f4a4fb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0f4a4fb1c4239a2aa46343add84ad6f99f6f3aae) (29 Mar 2019) by [Jonathan Tan (`jhowtan`)](https://github.com/jhowtan).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 32dc15d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/32dc15dec1cd9e9fada2983094484ae6e4c93647), 25 Apr 2019)</sup>

> ### `diff`: batch fetching of missing blobs

> When running a command like "`git show`" or "`git diff`" in a partial clone,
> batch all missing blobs to be fetched as one request.
>
> This is similar to [c0c578b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c0c578b33ca48ee6003d85706e13d97d12781354) ("`unpack-trees`: batch fetching of missing
> blobs", 2017-12-08, Git v2.17.0-rc0), but for another command.

---

Git 2.23 (Q3 2019) will futureproof that batch missing blob part.

See [commit 31f5256](https://github.com/git/git/commit/31f5256c82a36edea3ea2f91e5171e3472878915) (28 May 2019) by [Derrick Stolee (`derrickstolee`)](https://github.com/derrickstolee).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 5d5c46b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5d5c46b28c04348f7b680e5fe007c6344a86a70a), 17 Jun 2019)</sup>

> ### `sha1-file`: split `OBJECT_INFO_FOR_PREFETCH`

> The `OBJECT_INFO_FOR_PREFETCH` bitflag was added to `sha1-file.c` in [0f4a4fb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0f4a4fb1c4239a2aa46343add84ad6f99f6f3aae) (`sha1-file`: support `OBJECT_INFO_FOR_PREFETCH`, 2019-03-29, Git v2.22.0-rc0) and is used to prevent the `fetch_objects()` method when enabled.
>
> However, there is a problem with the current use.
> The definition of `OBJECT_INFO_FOR_PREFETCH` is given by adding 32 to `OBJECT_INFO_QUICK`.
> This is clearly stated above the definition (in a comment) that this is so
> `OBJECT_INFO_FOR_PREFETCH` implies `OBJECT_INFO_QUICK`.
> The problem is that using "`flag & OBJECT_INFO_FOR_PREFETCH`" means that `OBJECT_INFO_QUICK` also implies `OBJECT_INFO_FOR_PREFETCH`.
>
> Split out the single bit from `OBJECT_INFO_FOR_PREFETCH` into a new
> `OBJECT_INFO_SKIP_FETCH_OBJECT` as the single bit and keep
> `OBJECT_INFO_FOR_PREFETCH` as the union of two flags.

And "`git fetch`" into a lazy clone forgot to fetch base objects that are
necessary to complete delta in a thin packfile, which has been
corrected.

See [commit 810e193](https://github.com/git/git/commit/810e19322d0165e89faf560e65de61b9cd5d63dc), [commit 5718c53](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5718c53d0ab47cc750e05d2af4a401197117c2f0) (11 Jun 2019), and [commit 8a30a1e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8a30a1efd11bcfb7b0f5b8543492a09fc495ae60), [commit 385d1bf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/385d1bfd7ad5d49783a3956bba19d9feea9955b6) (14 May 2019) by [Jonathan Tan (`jhowtan`)](https://github.com/jhowtan).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 8867aa8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8867aa855e0c5cc7bc80589783295379ae63d175), 21 Jun 2019)</sup>

> ### `index-pack`: prefetch missing `REF_DELTA` bases

> When fetching, the client sends "`have`" commit IDs indicating that the
> server does not need to send any object referenced by those commits,
> reducing network I/O.
> When the client is a partial clone, the client still sends "`have`"s in this way, even if it does not have every object referenced by a commit it sent as "`have`".
>
> If a server omits such an object, it is fine: the client could lazily fetch that object before this fetch, and it can still do so after.
>
> The issue is when the server sends a thin pack containing an object that is a `REF_DELTA` against such a missing object: `index-pack` fails to fix
> the thin pack.
> When support for lazily fetching missing objects was added in [8b4c010](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8b4c0103a98239287176a537f7a04d9b07b49125) ("`sha1_file`: support lazily fetching missing objects", 2017-12-08, Git v2.17.0-rc0), support in `index-pack` was turned off in the belief that it accesses the repo only to do hash collision checks.
> However, this is not true: it also needs to access the repo to resolve
> **`REF_DELTA`** bases.
>
> Support for lazy fetching should still generally be turned off in index-pack because it is used as part of the lazy fetching process itself (if not, infinite loops may occur), but we do need to fetch the `REF_DELTA` bases.
> (When fetching `REF_DELTA` bases, it is unlikely that those are `REF_DELTA` themselves, because we do not send "`have`" when making such fetches.)
>
> To resolve this, prefetch all missing `REF_DELTA` bases before attempting
> to resolve them.
> This both ensures that all bases are attempted to be fetched, and ensures that we make only one request per index-pack invocation, and not one request per missing object.

---

Git 2.24 (Q4 2019) fixes on-demand object fetching in lazy clone, which incorrectly tried to fetch commits from submodule projects, while still working in the superproject.

See [commit a63694f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a63694f52355b412b65515961401cd2359fed544) (20 Aug 2019) by [Jonathan Tan (`jhowtan`)](https://github.com/jhowtan).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d8b1ce7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d8b1ce79729b1744727c29ec818c34ec43ee9599), 09 Sep 2019)</sup>

> ### `diff`: skip `GITLINK` when lazy fetching missing objs

> In [7fbbcb2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7fbbcb21b162883615d5542e06fb2eb8685fd496) ("`diff`: batch fetching of missing blobs", 2019-04-08, Git v2.22.0-rc0), `diff` was taught to batch the fetching of missing objects when operating on a partial clone, but was not taught to refrain from fetching
> GITLINKs.
> Teach diff to check if an object is a `GITLINK` before including it in the set to be fetched.

---

Git 2.24 (Q4 2019) also introduces the notion of **promisor** remote repository.

See [commit 4ca9474](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4ca9474efa4fd431c07a470513e684c5b2eec34c), [commit 60b7a92](https://github.com/git/git/commit/60b7a92d846a6cc542f96fa0045735cc0b9265fd), [commit db27dca](https://github.com/git/git/commit/db27dca5cfe41ffa62f3a34cff2f7fafb2547307), [commit 75de085](https://github.com/git/git/commit/75de0852119bc73c60ace232ba799c3cada2608a), [commit 7e154ba](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7e154badc007db7c99f0fb507a3893d7e333b7b2), [commit 9a4c507](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9a4c50788641887510876ea1b40c77daf9b7f7cf), [commit 5e46139](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5e46139376a4b8d31f02a521bdf801f3b8913e57), [commit fa3d1b6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fa3d1b63e866d6b893934ab69da10b4516150cdc), [commit b14ed5a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b14ed5adaf87c5943433fd6b1d2cbe8c060f9264), [commit faf2abf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/faf2abf496bb8e5a5fbf3818f3e78077b2f3e143), [commit 9cfebc1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9cfebc1f3b2b60290b6321b95e5038b6e5b758ab), [commit 9e27bea](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9e27beaa2344dc6dd422d7711a666c082785118f), [commit 48de315](https://github.com/git/git/commit/48de315817281e49a5e9000d40550b5257b437c6), [commit 2e86067](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2e860675b6572cf476e99888134a5b307fd7eb62), [commit c59c7c8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c59c7c879ef60b2b0d0b050982712c53ec4d0680) (25 Jun 2019) by [Christian Couder (`chriscool`)](https://github.com/chriscool).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit b9ac6c5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b9ac6c59b82dead613b31a51c8bca4dbd441bcbe), 18 Sep 2019)</sup>

The [`partial-clone` documentation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7e154badc007db7c99f0fb507a3893d7e333b7b2/Documentation/technical/partial-clone.txt#L33-L38) defines a promisor repo as:

> A remote that can later provide the missing objects is called a
> promisor remote, as it promises to send the objects when
> requested.
>
> Initialy Git supported only one promisor remote, the origin
> remote from which the user cloned and that was configured in the
> "`extensions.partialClone`" config option.
> Later support for more than one promisor remote has been implemented.
>
> Many promisor remotes can be configured and used.
>
> This allows for example a user to have multiple geographically-close
> cache servers for fetching missing blobs while continuing to do
> filtered `git-fetch` commands from the central server.
>
> Remotes that are considered "`promisor`" remotes are those specified by
> the following configuration variables:
>
> - `extensions.partialClone = <name>`
> - `remote.<name>.promisor = true`
> - `remote.<name>.partialCloneFilter = ...`
>
> Only one promisor remote can be configured using the `extensions.partialClone` config variable. This promisor remote will be the last one tried when fetching objects.

---

Git 2.24 (Q4 2019) *also* improves the notion of **filters** in a partial clone.

See [commit 90d21f9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/90d21f9ebf6906f0ebb4fb1b20ec9536072e2916), [commit 5a133e8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5a133e8a7f7c28c57f7a0a85e57692b8b781d896), [commit 489fc9e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/489fc9ee718b7c8594f17b55f090ac5292c655e1), [commit c269495](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c2694952e33764818983fa247dcee72113c6ac6a), [commit cf9ceb5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cf9ceb5a12cad9c9153d227a0f497d1b522ce085), [commit f56f764](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f56f764279be2433ecf3cb3a484210bcaffea70c), [commit e987df5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e987df5fe62b8b29be4cdcdeb3704681ada2b29e), [commit 842b005](https://github.com/git/git/commit/842b00516aebee06fc99c51a663b6587f642d36d), [commit 7a7c7f4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7a7c7f4a6d22477e3548021eb3571384651c00be), [commit 9430147](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9430147ca0aab0189d7e52df97b95a0985fc0c8a) (27 Jun 2019) by [Matthew DeVore (`matvore`)](https://github.com/matvore).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 627b826](https://github.com/git/git/commit/627b82683447e299fc2e20140318c276efbf7de2), 18 Sep 2019)</sup>

It allows for:

> - combining filters such that only objects accepted by all filters are shown.
>   The motivation for this is to allow getting directory listings without also fetching blobs. This can be done by combining `blob:none` with `tree:<depth>`.
>   There are massive repositories that have larger-than-expected trees - even if you include only a single commit.
>
> A combined filter supports any number of subfilters, and is written in
> the following form:
>
> ```
> combine:<filter 1>+<filter 2>+<filter 3>
> ```
>
> - combining of multiple filters by simply repeating the `--filter` flag.
>   Before, the user had to combine them in a single flag somewhat awkwardly (e.g. `--filter=combine:FOO+BAR`), including URL-encoding the individual filters.

---

With Git 2.27 (Q2 2020), "`git diff`" in a partial clone learned to avoid lazy loading blob objects in more cases when they are not needed.

See [commit 95acf11](https://github.com/git/git/commit/95acf11a3dc3d18ec999f4913ec6c6a54545c6b7), [commit c14b6f8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c14b6f83ec7453d2a93bba04f45caf26905f2bff), [commit 1c37e86](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1c37e86ab2834dfca311799e799568794bc474ce) (07 Apr 2020), and [commit db7ed74](https://github.com/git/git/commit/db7ed7418b3702ab2b2df755764c3f452917a890) (02 Apr 2020) by [Jonathan Tan (`jhowtan`)](https://github.com/jhowtan).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 8f5dc5a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8f5dc5a4af3fa32bf9261b76b0f1146fd15b8643), 28 Apr 2020)</sup>

> ### [`diff`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/95acf11a3dc3d18ec999f4913ec6c6a54545c6b7): restrict when prefetching occurs
>
> <sup>Helped-by: Jeff King</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jonathan Tan</sup>

> Commit [7fbbcb21b1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7fbbcb21b162883615d5542e06fb2eb8685fd496) ("`diff`: batch fetching of missing blobs", 2019-04-08, Git v2.22.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/32dc15dec1cd9e9fada2983094484ae6e4c93647) listed in [batch #7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/83232e38648b51abbcbdb56c94632b6906cc85a6)) optimized "`diff`" by prefetching blobs in a partial clone, but there are some cases wherein blobs do not need to be prefetched.
> In these cases, any command that uses the diff machinery will unnecessarily fetch blobs.

> `diffcore_std()` may read blobs when it calls the following functions:
>
> 1. `diffcore_skip_stat_unmatch()` (controlled by the config variable diff.autorefreshindex)
> 2. `diffcore_break()` and `diffcore_merge_broken()` (for break-rewrite detection)
> 3. `diffcore_rename()` (for rename detection)
> 4. `diffcore_pickaxe()` (for detecting addition/deletion of specified string)
>
> Instead of always prefetching blobs, teach `diffcore_skip_stat_unmatch()`, `diffcore_break()`, and `diffcore_rename()` to prefetch blobs upon the first read of a missing object.
> This covers (1), (2), and (3): to cover the rest, teach `diffcore_std()` to prefetch if the output type is one that includes blob data (and hence blob data will be required later anyway), or if it knows that (4) will be run.

---

Note the lazy fetching done internally to make missing objects available in a partial clone incorrectly made permanent damage to the partial clone filter in the repository, which has been corrected with Git 2.29 (Q4 2020).

See [commit 23547c4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/23547c40518ac04a20acf2f688114f5d97b61f24) (28 Sep 2020), and [commit 625e7f1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/625e7f148e46c7e09f817ce6ab25f14d4e753f1e) (21 Sep 2020) by [Jonathan Tan (`jhowtan`)](https://github.com/jhowtan).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e68f0a4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e68f0a4e574f38beeac513e824b685965dda31b7), 05 Oct 2020)</sup>

> ### [`fetch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/23547c40518ac04a20acf2f688114f5d97b61f24): do not override partial clone filter
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jonathan Tan</sup>

> When a fetch with the `--filter` argument is made, the configured default filter is set even if one already exists. This change was made in [5e46139376](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5e46139376a4b8d31f02a521bdf801f3b8913e57) ("`builtin/fetch`: remove unique promisor remote limitation", 2019-06-25, Git v2.24.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b9ac6c59b82dead613b31a51c8bca4dbd441bcbe) listed in [batch #3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4c86140027f4a0d2caaa3ab4bd8bfc5ce3c11c8a)) - in particular, changing from:
>
> - If this is the FIRST partial-fetch request, we enable partial
> - on this repo and remember the given filter-spec as the default
> - for subsequent fetches to this remote.
>
> to:
>
> - If this is a partial-fetch request, we enable partial on
> - this repo if not already enabled and remember the given
> - filter-spec as the default for subsequent fetches to this
> - remote.
>
> (The given filter-spec is "remembered" even if there is already an existing one.)
>
> This is problematic whenever a lazy fetch is made, because lazy fetches are made using "[`git fetch --filter=blob:none`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/23547c40518ac04a20acf2f688114f5d97b61f24/Documentation/git-fetch.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch))</sup>, but this will also happen if the user invokes "[`git fetch --filter=<filter>`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/23547c40518ac04a20acf2f688114f5d97b61f24/Documentation/git-fetch.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch))</sup>" manually. Therefore, restore the behavior prior to [5e46139376](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5e46139376a4b8d31f02a521bdf801f3b8913e57), which writes a filter-spec only if the current fetch request is the first partial-fetch one (for that remote).

Comment: Note: the `filter=blob:none` has a last-minute fix: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52916879/6309

Comment: See also the [Git 2.45 new option `--no-lazy-fetch`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78126447/6309)

Answer (score 5):

There's a subtree module for git, allowing you to split off a portion of a repository into a new repo and then merge changes to/from the original and the subtree. Here's its readme on github: http://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree/blob/master/git-subtree.txt

Comment: *Thanks* very much.   Even 3 years later, this is helpful - although I suppose that it is likely that git-subtrees has not been maintained.

Comment: No commits since 2012-07, but still seems interesting.

Answer (score 5):

> In distributed rcs the history of a file (or a chunk of content) is a directed acyclic graph, so why can't you just clone this single DAG instead of the set of all graphs in the a repository?

At least in Git, the DAG representing the repository history applies to the *whole* repository, not just a single file. Each commit object points to a "tree" object which represents the entire state of the repository at that time.

Git 1.7 supports ["sparse checkouts"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336580/sparse-checkout-in-git-1-7-0), which allow you to restrict the size of your working copy. The entire repository data is still cloned, however.

Comment: Ok this answers my question at least for git. I wonder whether every distributed rcs is designed this way or if you can have a design that allows splitting and joining of repositories.

Comment: @Jakob: I think they are because that's what gives you atomic commits. You have to go back to the dark days of CVS to get a version control system that stores revisions on files separately. You don't want to do that.

Answer (score 3):

In bazaar you can split and join parts of a repository.

The split-command allows you to split a repository into multiple repositories. The join-command allows you to merge repositories. Both keep the history.

However this isn't as handy a the SVN-model, where you can checkout/commit for a sub-tree.

There's a planned feature called [Nested-Trees](http://wiki.bazaar.canonical.com/NestedTreesDesign) for bazaar, which maybe would allow partial checkouts.

Comment: Hm, I tried split and join but they keep the whole history instead of only the history of a subset of the repository. The fast-import plugin (https://launchpad.net/bzr-fastimport) seems to do the job but afterwards I cannot merge updates from the source repository which I split from. I hope that nested trees is not vaporware.

Comment: I'm not 100%, but bazaar has only global versions and history. Each change-set applies to the whole repository. So when you split, the whole history applies also for the sub-directory. Thats why the whole history is still there after the split. Except that some entries don't have any effect. 

Nested-Trees: I don't know. Let's hope it's not vaporware.

Answer (score 3):

I hope one of these RCS's will add narrow clone capability.  My understanding is that the architecture of GIT (changes/moves tracked across the whole repo) makes this very difficult.

Bazaar prides itself on supporting many different types of workflows.  Lack of narrow clone capability prohibits an SVN/CVS like workflow in bzr/hg/git, so I'm hoping they'll be motivated to find some way to do this.

New features shouldn't come at the expense of basic functionality, like the ability to fetch a single file/directory from the repo.  The "distributed" feature of modern rcs's is "cool," but in my opinion discourages good development practices (frequent merges / continuous integration).  These new RCS's all seem to lack very basic functionality.  Even SVN without real branching/tagging support seemed like a step backwards from CVS imo.

Answer (score 1):

From `git help clone` :

`--depth <depth>
           Create a shallow clone with a history truncated to the specified number of revisions. A shallow repository has a number of limitations (you
           cannot clone or fetch from it, nor push from nor into it), but is adequate if you are only interested in the recent history of a large project
           with a long history, and would want to send in fixes as patches.`

Does that provide something like what you're looking for?