# How to associate a clearcase view with stream or vob?

Tags: clearcase

Below command is to make a view:
**ct mkview -tag *myview* /var/tmp/your-username_dynview.vws**

However, how do we know that [*myview*] is a view to certain stream ?
There's no specified arguments on above command indicating which stream a view is for.

Please read this:
https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.tutorial.doc/topics/a_crview_ux.htm

Is it because that above command is for base clearcase view, not for UCM view ?
If so, how it is possible for a view to work with stream or vob in base clearcase ?
I'm confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `-stream` parameter (following [cleartool `mkview` man page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkview.htm)).

```
ct mkview -tag myview -stream MyStream@/vobs:MyPVob /var/tmp/your-username_dynview.vws
```

See for instance "[How do I create a snapshot view of some project or stream in ClearCase?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1367656/6309)".

```
-str/eam stream-selector
```

> Specifies a UCM stream. The view being created is attached to this stream. (Cannot be used with –reg/ion.)
>
> `stream-selector` is of the form `[stream:]stream-name[@vob-selector]`, where `vob-selector` specifies the stream's project VOB.

So the `-stream` is the only difference between a base ClearCase view, and an UCM view.

Comment: How does base clearcase create the view without a stream option then?

Comment: @Jaeh a base ClearCase view doesn't need the stream option. If you are using -stream, then you are creating an UCM view. For more on the difference between base and UCM ClearCase: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464450/choosing-between-ucm-and-base-clearcase/4464793#4464793.

Comment: @Jaeh in your case, you have created a *base* ClearCase view, but if you intended to associate to a stream, you need to delete it and re-create it, this time with the `-stream` additional paramet.