# Creation of Integration View

Tags: clearcase

I have created a development stream **str_Devlopment_stream** in the integration stream **str_Integration_stream** .

While creating a development stream we get an option to create integration and development view, which creates an integration view in the integration stream and development view in the development stream.

Now what had happened with me is, the integration view was not created created properly and development view created completely. Due to this I have removed the integration view mistakenly.

Now I have made my project changes completely in the development view and checked in all the files. Now I am unable to deliver my changes from development stream to integration stream as the integration view is missing.

I would like to know if there is any way I can create this integration view in the respective integration stream so that I can deliver my changes from development stream to integration stream and make a baseline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to know if there is any way I can create this integration view in the respective integration stream

Sure, simply use [`cleartool mkview`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkview.htm?lang=en) (here a dynamic view, easier and quicker for merges, instead of a [snapshot view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2925378/6309))

```
ct mkview -tag myview -stream MyStream@/vobs:MyPVob /var/tmp/your-username_dynview.vws
```

See "[How to associate a clearcase view with stream or vob?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13363572/6309)"

Then make sure this new view is used for your [`cleartool deliver`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_deliver.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.0%2F9-1-0-2-6&lang=en):

```
cleartool deliver -reset -to your-integration-view
```

---

As mentioned in the discussion, the full name of the stream is important, and depends on the syntax for that environment (Windows or Linux)

A simple cleartool lsvob|grep vob name can help to have the right name

Then create the view with (in this case) a unix syntax:

```
cleartool mkview -tag myintview -stream astream_Integration@/vob/a_pvob /var/tmp/user_astream_int_URL.vws
```

Finally, initiate the deliver from dev stream to int stream and int view:

```
cleartool deliver -stream dev_stream@/vob/a_pvob -to myintview -target astream_Integration@/vob/a_pvob
```

Comment: ct mkview -tag myview -stream MyStream@/vobs:MyPVob /var/tmp/your-username_dynview.vws......................  Is this command for creating integration view

Comment: @niks indeed: that is what I describe in http://stackoverflow.com/a/13363572/6309. What ClearCase version are you using? Are you using it on Linux or on Windows?

Comment: Vonc: I am using in Linux with cleartool. I am able to create the dynamic integration view, currently unable to deliver using the command cleartool deliver -reset -to your-integration-view

Comment: cleartool deliver -stream My_Development_Stream -to My_Intgeration_View -target My_Intgeration_Stream

Comment: @niks do you refer to a stream with its full qualified name? IntStream@/vobs/aPVob? (replacing IntStream and aPVob by an actual stream name and an actual pvob)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92840/discussion-between-niks-and-vonc).