# Clearcase UCM in UNIX Build environment

Tags: unix, clearcase-ucm, auto-build

I am planning to use CC UCM in my project. (Actually migration from base clearcase to UCM)
The build environment is in UNIX. But the development is mostly done on windows.

My main doubt is that the snapshot views will be residing on the developers windows machine ?
How should the mapping to the UNIX build machine of the same should/can be done ?

How can we effectively make use triggers inorder to setup auto-build on delivery, nightly builds etc.. in UNIX environment?

Has anyone tried the same kind of configuration? If so please share your experiences.

After creating the UCM PVob and importing the existing Base clearcase (Component) VOB into it, Can we work on the component VOB through Base as well as UCM parallely ? will it be in sync with each other?

Comment: I have edited my answer to address your additional questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My main doubt is that the snapshot views will be residing on the developers windows machine?

Yes. Nothing change compared with Base ClearCase.
The definition of those UCM view is based on an UCM stream, but otherwise, the snapshot or dynamic views keep the same behavior.

I was used to manage base ClearCase views, and UCM views referring the same Vobs actually (both can coexist).

I managed an introp environment, and triggers works the same with UCM or non-UCM views.
You simply need to define those trigger with a `-unix` parameter in order toreference a shared path (accessible/readible by all) for said trigger to access its script.
See [`cleartool mktrtype`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mktrtype.htm).

---

The [OP Karshal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3515443/harshal) asks (in [an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4915164))

> Can you please elaborate a little more on the triggers for nightly build, Continous integration build kickofff etc... and mainly the baselining strategy?

I don't have specifics on the triggers (you write your own), but the baseline strategy is mainly to use:

- incremental baselines (quick to set, especially if the number of modified elements since the last baseline is small)
- full baselines for stable main releases.

See more at "[What is the difference between Full baseline and Incremental baseline in Clearcase UCM?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9696988/6309)"

> After creating the UCM PVob and importing the existing Base clearcase (Component) VOB into it, Can we work on the component VOB through Base as well as UCM parallely ? will it be in sync with each other?

Yes, but you might want to work on parallel branches and do a merge to synchronize their content instead of working on the same branch.
Again: yes, a file which is part of an UCM component can be checked-out checked-in in a base ClearCase view.

See more at:

- "[What are all the steps to migrate from Base clearcase to UCM?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9600531/6309)"
- "[Choosing between UCM and base ClearCase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4464793/6309)"