# Multiple projects or VOBs?

Tags: clearcase, configuration-management, clearcase-ucm

I just took over a ClearCase UCM admin position recently, so any input on this post would be great.

We are currently using one VOB with one project.  Say the project that we are working on is the software for a Car, CAR X.

Right now, there is one VOB, one component, and one project called 'CAR X' where everyone (maybe 12-15 developers) works on the software for the car.

In the future, we will probably need to make software for a new car, called 'CAR Y' which may be based off of the software that is used for 'CAR X' with modifications.  We would like these to be somewhat separate.  Should a new VOB be created or just a new component within the current VOB?  If a new VOB and project is created, the files could be imported and modified from the new project, correct?  Is there a downside to having one component used for each project housed in the same VOB?

This is complicated to explain, so hopefully I was able to get the idea across.  If you need me to be more specific or answer any questions, please leave a comment.

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the number of vobs you can expect to create over the next few months /years.

I prefer creating multiple components within a (generalically named) vob, rather than limiting a vob to one component (especially when this latter choice cannot be reversed)

You easily can define 100 components within a vob.
Trying to create / manage 100 vobs is almost impossible in term of ressources involved (too many processes)

If you *know* you only a few of those vobs to create, go ahead.
But my point remains: multiple components per vob is a model you can scale.

Comment: Thank you @VonC - that's exactly what I was looking for.  So I can have a CARX, CARY, CARZ, etc components all in one vob and have one project attached to each component?  That's what I was hoping for, I would rather not have to maintain more than one (maybe two) VOBs.

Comment: @Rubasu: sure, see http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_proj.doc/t_u_prj_vb_cre_mc_win.htm for the practical aspect of it. But **make sure you organize yours components all one level below the vob**: see the last part of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764329/clearcase-ucm-best-practices-using-components/1766662#1766662 .

Comment: Would it be possible to send you a private message?  I just have a few questions, but they are specific to my project and really don't have any business being on here.

Comment: @Rubasu sure: vonc at laposte dot net