# importing a RationalTeamConcert SCM to Clearcase

Tags: clearcase, rtc, ibm-rational

I'm trying to import a full RTC repository into a ClearCase VOB. I have tried using clearfsimport but it seems like it only take the latest version of the files. Is there any way to import the code while retaining history (comments, renames etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Such an import should be done component by component into a [UCM components Vob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10017263/6309), and not into a plain Base ClearCase Vob.
UCM components (and streams) map quite nicely with the RTC component and Streams, but with `clearfsimport`, the import process would still be:

- manual (in that you would have to select each RTC baseline you want to see in order to ['clearfsimport' them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416875/creating-a-new-subdirectory-structure-in-clearcase/418196#418196))
- done for baselines only (it would be too long to import *all* the RTC revisions)
- without metadata like merges or rename

**In theory, it is possible** (but I haven't tested it), through one of the [ClearCase-RTC connectors](https://jazz.net/library/article/785) called "ClearCase Synchronizer".

> **ClearCase Synchronizer** is a two-way data replication between ClearCase and Rational Team Concert source control.
>   You can choose a UCM stream or a ClearCase branch and set up synchronization with a stream of Rational Team Concert source control.
>   It leverages Jazz Team Build, and you can run the synchronization on a scheduled basis or as you request.
>   This will provide flexibility to enterprise customers to let subset of teams to choose SCM tools to work with, and yet manage all the latest source code by single SCM repository.

See "[Using the Rational ClearCase Synchronizer and Importer](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.team.connector.scm.cc.doc/topics/c_sync_intro.html&re=1&scope=null)".
But I don't know how well it can work (or if it works at all) with an empty UCM component on one side, and a full-history RTC component on the other.

[image: ClearCase synchronizer]