# RTC source control icons

Tags: clearcase, rtc

What is the difference between these two RTC source control icons ? Is it identifying which workspace is loaded by which component ? Is there a reference that explains each of the RTC source control icons ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each represents a component (RTC component, which has the same semantic than a [ClearCase UCM component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764329/clearcase-ucm-best-practices-using-components/1766662#1766662): a coherent set of files, branched or  labelled as a whole unit).

- the blue one represents a component loaded in a local workspace (or sandbox)
- the white one represents a component not loaded (only declared in a repository workspace)

[image: repo workspace]

Note that you would always see:

- a blue one in the "Component" section of a Project Area, but that just designate the component itself, not its loaded or not-loaded state.
- a white one in the components listed on a Stream section of a project area: components declared on a Stream aren't loaded or not (it makes no sense in that context)
- a blue one in the Stream displayed in a flow diagram (see last illustration bellow). Again it doesn't mean that component is loaded or not, it just means the code color convention isn't very coherent *outside* of repository workspace...

Within a repository workspace, the meaning is clear: blue equals "loaded", white equals "not loaded" (in a sandbox).

[image: stream]

You can use the flow diagram to see who has loaded what (see article "[Easing into Jazz Source Control](https://jazz.net/library/article/539/)"):

[image: flow diagram]

Answer (score 4):

Also see the section called "Icons used in Rational Team Concert Source Control" at the following link: http://thescmlounge.blogspot.com/2012/11/icons-used-in-rational-team-concert.html

This link not only answers your question about the component icons (representing a loading and not-loaded component), but other icons used in Jazz SCM.