# When to use multiple components within a stream in RTC source control

Tags: version-control, clearcase, rtc

An RTC source control component as I see it is a logical grouping of files & folders.

When should I use multiple components within a stream in RTC source control?

**Method 1:**
I have multiple java(Eclipse) projects but I am adding these projects to just one component within a single stream. These projects are packaged into one deployment file.

**Method 2:**
Each java project be added to its own component within the stream, so the stream will contain multiple components - one component for each java project.

Are there advantages/disadvantages to using one method over the other ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An RTC component has really the same meaning than an [ClearCase UCM component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764329/clearcase-ucm-best-practices-using-components/1766662#1766662).

The goal, when using multiple component, is to divide your huge set of files into coherent and logical subsets, more identifiable and manageable.

> Example of components:
>
> - an application (or a autonomous part of an application)
> - a technical library
> - a packaged set of file (for release)

Note: in RTC, you can reuse a component (defined in one project area) in *another* project area (provided both PA are on the same Jazz server).

A Java project can be represented as one component, but certain Java project could be seen as several components (one for the business logic, one for database logic, and so on)

The main criteria when you define a component is:
Will it evolve at its own pace? Can you modify it without having to modify another component?
(If not, that might mean the two set of files are tightly linked, and might be considered as one component).

From there, you must decide if you want to see all components on one Stream (system approach, with every component writable), or just one or two components per stream (depending on the deliveries - dll, jar, ... - produced by the other components): component approach.
For starter, stick with the system approach, simpler at first.