# Multiple components in a user repository workspace

Tags: clearcase, rtc

Whats the point of adding multiple components to a user repository workspace. From my understanding one component is required as this is the placeholder for the source code within the local repository, but why have multiple components ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in "[When to use multiple components within a stream in RTC source control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10120788/when-to-use-multiple-components-within-a-stream-in-rtc-source-control)", you define multiple components within a Stream in order to manage more easily your set of files into coherent sub-set.

This is the system approach, where you list all the components you need to build your system.

However, for a given task, you might not need *all* the component in order to complete said task.
That is why a repository workspace allows you to select only what you need to see in your "space" in order to work (work+space).
And even then, your *local* workspace (or sandbox) allows you to load (ie copy on your hard drive) only some of the selected components, or even a subset of one component (in order to avoid to copy *too many* files).

You would find a similar approach with the load rules of an ClearCase UCM Snapshot view, with:

- a config spec selecting *all* the components of a Stream
- but load rules only loading (copying) what you want on your hard-drive

So in the following schema (from [Jazz Source Control FAQ](https://jazz.net/library/article/126/)), the repo workspace doesn't have t have all the components declared on the Stream, and the local workspace doesn't have to load all the components of the repo workspace.

[image]

Comment: nice anology - "load rules only loading (copying) what you want on your hard-drive" thanks