# Clease case: Merge Manager: Error: Can't switch to baseline

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm, cleartool

In Clearcase Project Explorer, under the configuration tab of a feature stream, I select the main stream's recommended baseline and then do a rebase of the stream. This goes fine and then I do a recommend baseline. But when I rebase a child stream under this feature stream, I get the following error. Any idea whats wrong here?

```
The foundation configuration is invalid.
Switching to baseline "YYYYYYV50" of component "PPPP"
Switching to baseline "ZZZZZZZV50" of component "QQQQ"
Merge Manager: Error: Can't switch to baseline "TTTTTTT09V46"
of component "core" because the stream has made changes
based on the current baseline.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means:

- your component "`core`" is a composite component (it includes other component)
- your composite baseline "`TTTTTTT09V46`" of "`core`" include other baselines
- rebasing means changing the foundation baseline.

If you have made any modification on one of the sub-components, you could only rebase it by a more recent foundation baseline produced on the parent Stream.
So check if `"TTTTTTT09V46`" (and all the sub-baselines) have been created in the Feature Stream and are more recent than the foundation baseline used on the child stream.

If non-modifiable components are involved, check if this isn't a bug called "parasite baseline", as detailed in the "Final warning" section of the answer on "[ClearCase UCM - best practices using components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764329/clearcase-ucm-best-practices-using-components/1766662#1766662)".

Comment: Thanks. It seems the composite component "core" has a separate versioning inside the feature branch. So when I recommended the main streams "core" version, it created problems. Currently I recommend all components of the main stream except core and recommend the baseline of the core applicable inside the feature steams to the child feature streams and it works fine.