# how to create a preop trigger to prevent a new baseline in clearcase stream?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I have this issue while rebasing the stream:
cleartool: Error: Can't switch to baseline because the stream has made changes
based on the current baseline.

giraffe_pvob is a non modifiable component on
tiger_011 project and there were no changes done on this component
by the stream.

I would like to install the preop trigger to prevent any new baseline on this stream. so how should I proceed? Will this prevent any rebasing issue like above?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot prevent the creation of the baseline, but you can prevent the situation which leads to said baseline on a non-modifiable component.

This is called a **parasite baseline**, and is one of [UCM flaws](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1074785/6309).

It is caused by a dependency, as explained in "[ClearCase UCM - best practices using components](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1766662/6309)".

```
A1
  B1
B2
```

Putting a baseline on `A` will create a parasite baseline on `B`, even if `B` is a non-modifiable component...
(more details in [this thread](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000013798284))

The only preop I usually put is one (on rebase) making sure none of the foundation components (like `B`) of a stream are part of the dependencies of another (modifiable) component (like `A` depending on `B`)