# Git: linking a file from one repo to another, while receiving updates on file from its original repo

Tags: git

Example: Repo-A has a File-A I would like to include in Repo-B.  Whenever Repo-A updates File-A, I would like File-A in Repo-B to reflect those changes.

Reason:  I'm using hardlinked files to manage my dotfiles with git, and I love LS_COLORS by trapd00r.  I'd like to have all my dotfiles in one git repo, but I always want the latest LS_COLORS.

Comment: Is this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/769786/vendor-branches-in-git ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the simple way would be:

From repo `B`:

- soft link to `fileA` from repo `A` (symlinks are available even on Windows Vista or Seven)
- ignore `fileA` in repo `B` `.gitignore` file.

Submodules aren't appropriate here, especially when you consider a submodule always refers to a fixed commit (and they refer to a full Git repo, not to just one file).