# DVCS: Single source control repository across different programming languages?

Tags: version-control, development-environment, dvcs, multiple-languages

I have a system that's broken down to three different programming languages: C#, C++ and Java. The first two are managed in two separate Visual Studio solutions, the latter in an Eclipse project.

I would like to manage the source code for all three using a distributed version control system solution (DVCS). Specifically Mercurial.

Which of the following options would be better:
A. Have a single repository containing all the system's source code. Each of the 3 "language oriented" projects to reside in a different sub-folder.

B. Have one repository for each language oriented project. Totaling 3 independent repositories.

In both options I plan on managing the repository/ies by alternating between Visual Studio (TortoiseHg) and Eclipse (MercurialEclipse).

Thanks in advance, urig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a DVCS, a repository is generally tied to a "component", ie a coherent set of files which evolve as a all unit: if you modify one file, you will tag *all* the files.

So if you three set of files (one for each language) can evolve independently one from another (for example, one being at a version 1.2 while the other is at 3.4), then it is best to consider a separate repo for each group of files.
You can then group those repos as submodules, in a more "[component-based approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/769941/6309)".

If they are closely tied together, one modification in one group triggering modifications in the other groups of files, then one repo with separate directory is fine.