# ClearCase Project / Stream setup

Tags: version-control, clearcase-ucm

I am new to ClearCase UCM and I am simply curious about Projects/Streams.

I have a Mainline project which is a composite baseline of different components.  However, with the components, if I would like to have different release versions to break up the long line of changes, would it be better to have different streams or different projects for each release?

The reason I as is because it seems that over time, there may be too many projects/streams and some people may get confused.  Is there a way to only have certain projects show under a directory (in Project Explorer?)  Also, would it be good to have different versions of the Mainline Project as well?

(I am setting up a new PVOB, so any input would be appreciated, even if it's a new and better way to set something like this up.)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding "Composite Baseline", a good introduction can be found at "[Best practices for using composite baselines in UCM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/5134.html)".

You cannot filter easily by project in the Project Explorer though.

The idea behind projects vs stream is easy:

- a project is a Stream container
- a Stream represents a development effort

So when you have too many development efforts (Streams) in a Project, it is time to create a new project (with at least one "integration" Stream), that you can initialize with any baseline you want.
It is then clearer for the developers to see what project they should open (and search for their stream there).

If like to create one project per component, when said components can be developed independently one from another: it is a [component-based approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933723/what-is-component-driven-development/933735#933735).

If, in your case, you have *all* the components in the same stream (plus your composite component), then you would follow a [system-based approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769786/vendor-branches-in-git/769941#769941).

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, VonC.  So, one last question relating to this.  I have 5 components.  Should each component have a "Mainline" or should the only Mainline be where all of the different components of the project come together?  From what I am reading, it looks like each component should have a mainline, but it seems that it would take a lot of deliveries to get it from [Comp_Dev Stream] > [Comp_Int Stream] > [Comp_Mainline Stream] > [Project_Mainline Stream].  Unless I am way off base on this.

Comment: @Rubasu it depends on the kind of dependency you have between your component: source dependency (ie you modify the source of all components at the same time) means one Mainline in a system approach system. Binary dependency (ie each component builds with the binary produced by the other component) means separate mainlines, each evolving interdependently one from another in a component-based approach.