# how to include forked-repo in my project git repo?

Tags: git, github, project-management

Suppose you have a private git repository for your ambitious next-facebook project(A).

You find an awesome-but-need-modification github library(B) so you fork the repo.

How do you include the library(B) in your project git(A)?

as a submodule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)** if you want a [source dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4311451/6309) between the two projects.
Your project will reference a fixed SHA1 of `libraryB`, but you can configure a submodule to follow a branch: see "[Git submodules: Specify a branch/tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18799234/6309)".

In that case:

```
cd /path/to/next-facebook 
git submodule add https://url/to/libraryB
git submodule update --init
```

This is different from [subtree](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/), where the history of libraryB would be part of your own project.