# Completely independent Git project within another project using only gitignore

Tags: git, git-submodules, gitignore, subdirectory, git-subtree

Is it possible to work with two **independent** git projects, one within another in the directory tree and separate them using only gitignore (*without [submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811730/how-do-i-work-with-a-git-repository-within-another-repository) or [subtrees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720669/projects-within-projects-using-git)*)?

Here is the folder structure:

```
repo_a     <-- repository A folder
   /.git
   /folder_1
   /folder_2
   /repo_b    <-- repository B folder (to be ignored by repository A)
       /.git
       /folder_3
       /folder_4
```

Comment: you could have /repo_b in the gitignore of repo_a

Comment: From my experience, this is possible, but I recall outer projects ignoring inner ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible.
Configure the repo_a to ignore the repo_b by adding :

```
repo_b/
```

in the .gitignore

This will ingore the directory, meaning if you clone the repo_a it will not have an (empty) repo_b directory.